# Insertar Registro en Base remota mediante Batch en mysql desde JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Estoy Insertando registros en una base de datos remota mysql y lo hago mediante un java escritorio batch. Lo que me resulta raro es, que si bien logro insertar, el tiempo que me lleva me parece demasiado, aproximadamente 2 minutos (500 registros). La consulta particularmente es, cual es la manera optima de hacer esta operación, la verdad no encontre nada diferente a lo que estoy haciendo.
Muchas gracias

```
 Connection dbConnection = ncw.getDBConnection();//conexion a la base en servidor del hosting
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pst = dbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6,campo7,campo8, campo9, campo10,campo11,campo12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 

        int filas = nc.getCantFilas();
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < 12; f++) {          
                pst.setString(f, nc.getDato(i, f)); 
                             }
            pst.addBatch();
        }
         pst.executeBatch();
        dbConnection.commit();
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos el código para poder ayudar... de otra manera, imposible.

Comment: ¿Qué es nc? quizás esto esta gatillando la lentitud.

Comment: es una clase que me trae la informacion de una consulta, la demora comienza luego del pst.executebatch().  Cuando sube la informacion al hosting.